# How to use Prepared Statement for Microsoft SQL Xpath queries in java

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, xpath

I am having a hard time trying to use Prepared Statement for the below `sql xml xpath` query in `java`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE_DTLS 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_DTLS.EMP_XML.exist('//emp/empId[text()[1]=?]')= 1 AND 
(EMPLOYEE_DTLS.EMP_XML.exist('//emp/designationList/designation[contains(.,?)]')= 1 OR
  EMPLOYEE_DTLS.EMP_XML.exist('//emp/designationList/designation[contains(.,?)]')= 1 OR  1!=1)
```

I would like to set values to all places with `?` symbol. Since the `?` is inside the single quotes in xpath, it is not considered as a placeholder and I am unable to set the values. Can someone help me on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly specifying a parametrized value in an XPath (or XQuery) expression is not possible. What you can do however, is refer to a variable using the `sql:variable("variable_name")` function in XPath (XQuery) expressions.

So you'd have a script like:

```sql
DECLARE @some_variable NVARCHAR(128)=?; -- specify the parameter here
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE_DTLS 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_DTLS.EMP_XML.exist('//emp/empId[text()[1]=sql:variable("@some_variable")]')=1 -- etc.
```

---

You can find documentation on the `sql:variable()` function → [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) ←

Comment: @user2186831 Hi again, I think it's best that you create a new question with as much detail to your problem as possible. Ideally with a data sample to test on, which shows the problem you are having.